# How to configure Apache 2 to use a proxy server for external request?

Tags: django, proxy, apache2

We're making a web application in my company with Django on an Apache2 server. This web app is used in a local network but it sometimes needs to access the internet.

If the user got a proxy server on his network, it needs to be configured.
So we made a little configuration on our app and on the Linux server. But the problem is that Apache 2 does not use the proxy configuration. We tried to set environment variables for proxy:

```
HTTP_PROXY=proxyserver.com:8080
http_proxy=proxyserver.com:8080
```

And we also used mod_proxy (apache2 module) with this command in our conf-available file:

```
ProxyRemote "*" "proxyserver.com:8080"
```

None of this solutions work.

If someone knows anything about this problem, let us know :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from internal.example.com
</Proxy>
```

or

```
<Proxy http://backend.example.com>
ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30 </Proxy>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: I try it, but none of your two solutions worked. Maybe I don't use thie conf at the right place. Where should I use it? In my conf file in conf-available or in my site file in site-available?

Edit : And I don't understand one thing, proxy directive means my server is a proxy, but it is not that I would like.